# How can I recall the previous title of a question after it has been edited

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, revisions-list

The title of a question I posted on StackOverflow was edited.

I looked into the recent activity revisions page and was surprised to find that:

1. The link title for all activity related to the question now showed the new title
2. No entry mentioning that title was edited appeared in the log

At a minimum, I would like to see an entry in the log stating "title was changed from `'old title'`".

Comment: A link to that post may help in answering your question.

Comment: @Aziz: click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334415/adding-add-on-bar-to-a-custom-xulrunner-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8334415/revisions) of that question (click on the "edited two days ago" link) clearly documents that the question title changed from *"What do I have to do to get Firefox to display the add-on bar and XUL simultaneously?"* to *"Adding add-on bar to a custom XULRunner application"*, two days ago, with the change note *"clarfiy the question by replacing XUL -> XUL Application, add the information from a comment by the OP"*.

Comment: Yes it does.  How long has the revision diff been available... I've never used it before.  I've been relying on the [activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/201008/smileandnod?tab=activity), which is what my feature request pertains to.

Comment: It's been there as long as I can remember. You didn't make the change, so it doesn't appear on your activity tab.

Comment: Is there a clickable link, or does the reviewer have to manually enter the url ["http://stackoverflow.com/posts/"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/), the question number (eg "8334415"), and the suffix "/revisions"?

Comment: As I mention in my answer, click on on the "edited two days ago" link.

Comment: It's 2:30am here.. I apologize.